# Link with "&": ampersand not insert into database

Tags: php, mysqli, hyperlink, ampersand

How to insert in database a link with a html special chars like `&` (ampersand) symbol ? When I inserted it, the output is cut out..

For example: this link

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCnxD9V9lGE&index=24&list=PLNVssP8zTtVk5asCmP703gEvR_lG-Ur-S

and the output after I've inserted it:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCnxD9V9lGE

The `&` (ampersand) symbol and the rest is cut out.

This is my code:

```
$data = "LINK with & (ampersand)";

$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db, $data);
```

Comment: The code you've quoted doesn't insert anything into a database

Comment: This is not a problem with insert. Most likely it gets truncated where you *displaying* this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using prepared queries. This will prevent most problems with special characters being inserted into databases. PDO is the best way (imo) to use prepared statements. This is roughly how your code would look using PDO:

```
$connect_db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=yourdb;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$url = //your url with ampersands
$insertquery = $connect_db->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (urlstring, ...) VALUES (:url,...)");
$insertquery->bindParam(':url',$url);
$insertquery->execute();
```

Getting familiar with prepared queries will also help prevent SQL injection. Once you're a bit more confident with PHP, take a look at this guide for PDO: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo