# PHP file_get_contents uses &amp; instead of & in the OpenStreetMap API and returns a 403

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, decode, encode

I use the **OpenStreetMap API** to get back **XML**. So basically using [Search for Test](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=test&format=xml) (with `?q=test&format=xml`) is e.g. finding a river in England. So far so good.

My issue is that the API is very restrictive. So searching for [Search for Test](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=test&format=xml) (with `q=test&amp;format=xml`) is (when using a usual browser) redirecting to the url above. But if you **copy paste** the URL with `?q=test&format=xml` it should look like this here: **[image: failing request]**

This is not an XML. So the URL is not conform for OpenStreetMap. Because the `format` parameter is not recognized now anymore.

And that's just my issue. So when I try to use in PHP: `file_get_contents("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=test&format=xml");`

I get the exception:

> Exception has occurred. Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=test&format=xml):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

[image]

I'm not totally sure what causes this `&amp;` rewrite. Is it OpenStreetMap or PHP `file_get_contents`? I had a look on the following questions already. But sadly none of those solutions did help me out:

- [Link with "&": ampersand not insert into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157652/link-with-ampersand-not-insert-into-database)
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52822/api-demands-and-not-amp
- [php file_get_contents($url) & turns into &amp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120211/php-file-get-contentsurl-turns-into-amp)
- [PHP Get Content of HTTP 400 Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710147/php-get-content-of-http-400-response) (no solution for me to simply ignore error)
- [php file_get_contents and &amp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656940/php-file-get-contents-and-amp)

Also tried to play with the php.ini values of:

- arg_separator.output = "&"
- arg_separator.input = ";&"

Comment: You could show us the code you're using, in case there's anything in there. Basically what's happening is a URL-encode, but the question is why?

Comment: Actually this is all code  `file_get_contents("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=test&format=xml");` Just fire this and you will get the 403 error code. And that's my question at all. Why I'm not getting back an XML here?

Comment: Duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30120429/6449659

Comment: Not really as NONE of the Answers helped me. So maybe the API is something special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was **not** an issue of the `&amp;`. By **fixing** the **403 error** it's working properly. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700300/http-nominatim-openstreetmap-org-api-giving-httpcode-403) helped me to find a solution as OpenStreetMap now requires a http referer.

So this code fixes my issue:

```
  $referer = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=test&format=xml";
  $opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'header'=>array("Referer: $referer\r\n")
    )
  );
  $context = stream_context_create($opts);
  $myURL = file_get_contents($referer, false, $context);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$referer = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=test&format=xml";
```

Please change XML to JSON, then get data from API server.

Answer (score 0):

We could pass a `stream_context` into `file_get_contents`.

```
file_get_contents("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=50,0.51&format=json",
  0,
  stream_context_create(["http"=>["header"=> "Referer: testbot\r\n"]])
)
// 200 OK
```